# Delphi ISAPI: How to access Accept-Language in an Apache host?

Tags: apache, delphi, http, isapi

I wrote a web service using content-negotiation with ISAPI using Delphi XE4.

My code contains

```
ARequest.GetFieldByName('Accept-Language')
```

which outputs the correct value if I use a standalone server (Indy Bridge), but it is empty if I use an ISAPI DLL inside Apache.

Is there any way I can access this header field with ISAPI in Apache?

Comment: Why use ISAPI in Apache httpd? With the unit `HTTPD2.pas` you can write an Apache httpd module.

Comment: We started with ISAPI because we want to leave the option open to switch to IIS someday. At the moment our server is running in Apache. Everything works, except for that "easy" task to access a HTTP header.

Comment: Sounds like exactly what I made http://xxm.sf.net/ for.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since ISAPI is kind-of a successor to CGI, the 'default' HTTP headers get converted to CGI-style parameters, so you need to request `HTTP_ACCEPT_LANGUAGE` using the extension control block's `GetServerVariable`. Like so:

```
function GetVar(pecb: PEXTENSION_CONTROL_BLOCK; const key:AnsiString):AnsiString;
var
  l:cardinal;
begin
  l:=$10000;
  SetLength(Result,l);
  if not(pecb.GetServerVariable(pecb.ConnID,PAnsiChar(key),PAnsiChar(Result),l)) then
    if GetLastError=ERROR_INVALID_INDEX then l:=1 else RaiseLastOSError;
  SetLength(Result,l-1);
end; 

//
GetVar(ecb,'HTTP_ACCEPT_LANGUAGE')
```

Comment: Thanks for your help! Your answer was a bit confusing because I have no access to the PECB through TWebRequest. But simply Request.GetFieldByName('HTTP_ACCEPT_LANGUAGE') did work on Apache. However, it did not work for the standalone EXE because only Request.GetFieldByName('Accept-Language') works there. So I have written a small function which tries both (see my own answer below). Can you please tell me if this is a clean solution? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I used following function to make it work on Apache and the standalone EXE:

```
function GetHTTPHeader(ARequest: TWebRequest; AHeaderName: AnsiString): AnsiString;

  function ConvertToCGIStyle(AStr: AnsiString): AnsiString;
  var
    tmp: string;
  begin
    tmp := string(AStr); // "tmp" used to avoid Unicode warnings
    tmp := UpperCase(tmp);
    tmp := StringReplace(tmp, '-', '_', [rfReplaceAll]);
    tmp := 'HTTP_' + tmp;
    result := AnsiString(tmp);
  end;

begin
  // will work on Indy Standalone EXE
  result := ARequest.GetFieldByName(AHeaderName);

  if result = '' then
  begin
    // will work on Apache ISAPI DLL
    AHeaderName := ConvertToCGIStyle(AHeaderName);
    result := ARequest.GetFieldByName(AHeaderName);
  end;
end;

GetHTTPHeader(ARequest, 'Accept-Language');
```